# Swipe without tab content overlapping

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have created a swipe view with tabs, but when swiping between tabs, the content that was in the tab will slide with your finger, and the previous tabs' content will overlap with the tab being swiped in.

For example:

[image]

Here's my `MainActivity.java`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Fragment tab1Fragment = new Tab1();
    Fragment tab2Fragment = new Tab2();
    Fragment tab3Fragment = new Tab3();

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //Instantiate the tabs.
        tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab3 = actionBar.newTab();

        //Set the tabs' text.
        tab1.setText("Tab 1");
        tab2.setText("Tab 2");
        tab3.setText("Tab 3");

        //Setting up the tab listeners
        tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(tab1Fragment));
        tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(tab2Fragment));
        tab3.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(tab3Fragment));

        //Adding tabs to the ActionBar
        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(tab3);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

`MyTabListener.java`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class MyTabListener implements android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
        ft.attach(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

`Tab1.java` (`Tab2.java` and `Tab3.java` are similar):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_layout, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

`TabsPagerAdapter.java`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new Tab1();
            case 1:
                return new Tab2();
            case 2:
                return new Tab3();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   android:id="@+id/pager"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

`tab1_layout.xml` (`tab2_layout.xml` and `tab3_layout.xml` are similar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is tab 1."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried adding a background color in the tab XML layout files, but then there would be no sliding animation at all. My Android version is 4.4.2, I don't know if the issue is related to that. How can I solve this so that the tabs swipe without overlapping content with the previous tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See explanation given on [Developer site - adding tabs with swipe view](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

don't call add() or attach methods but do like this:

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the new support design library, the new TabLayout makes writing swipe layouts easier and since ActionBar tabs are now deprecated by Google.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

Answer (score 0):

In your **class MyTabListener**  change

```
android.R.id.content
```

by this

```
R.id.action_bar_activity_content
```

Which android support library are you using? This problem was fixed in *Support Library v19*?

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58108) you have more information about this